# how to check str int list and tuple?

Tags: python, string, list, class, python-3.x

there is a file include str int list and tuple. I want to put them in different list.

this is my example code:

```
for word in file:
    if type(word) == int:
        ......
    if type(word) == list:
        ......
```

I can check int use type(word) == int

but I can't use 'type(word) == list' in my code.

so, How to check a file is 'list' or 'tuple'?

Comment: Everything you read out of a text file is a `str`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work-

```
for word in file:
    if isinstance(word, int):
        ...
    elif isinstance(word, list):
        ...
    elif isinstance(word, tuple):
        ...
    elif isinstance(word, str):
        ...
```

Comment: All of the `word` that you get from iterating through `file` will be Strings.  If I'm not mistaken, only the line `elif isinstance(word,str)` will actually evaluate to `True`.

Answer (score -1):

If there is no pattern you can exploit to predict what each line of the file will represent, ahead of time, you can try this quick and dirty solution:

```
for word in file:
    # Read the word as the appropriate type (int, str, list, etc.)
    try:
        word = eval(word) # will be as though you pasted the line from the file directly into the Python file (e.g. "word = 342.54" if word is the string "342.54").  Works for lists and tuples as well.
    except:
        pass # word remains as the String that was read from the file

    # Find what type it is and do whatever you're doing
    if type(word) == int:
        # add to list of ints
    elif type(word) == list:
        # add to list of lists
    elif type(word) == tuple:
        # add to list of tuples
    elif type(word) == str:
        # add to list of strs
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use types

```
from types import *
type(word) == ListType
type(word) == TupleType
```

As your question, you could simply code as:

```
>>> from types import *
>>> file = [1,"aa",3,'d',[23,1],(12,34)]
>>> int_list = [item for item in file if type(item)==int]
>>> int_list
[1, 3]
```

Comment: I have tried it but it don't work. Im using python shell.

Comment: @Vinceeema  Then could you give an example of your "file" variable? I thought it was a iterable object with str int list and tuple in it. Such as a result of pickle.load