# __iter__: int and str vs list and tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
some_obj = "scalar"
list_like = "__iter__" in dir(some_obj)   # Py2: False; Py3: True
```

I used it in python 2 to distinguish between "non-iterables" (`str`, `int`, `bool`, `None`) and iterables (`list`, `dict`, `tuples`).

This does not work with python3 anymore, since `str` has now the `__iter__` attribute  ([Why do strings in python 2.7 not have the "__iter__" attribute, but strings in python 3.7 have the "__iter__" attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58328946/why-do-strings-in-python-2-7-not-have-the-iter-attribute-but-strings-in-p)).

Well, often it is desirable to regard `str` not as list-like. So is there a better py2+py3 way then `"__iter__" in dir(some_obj) and not type(some_obj)==str` or all the case checks in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025980/how-to-check-str-int-list-and-tuple)?
Do I miss other objects that are disputable like `str`?

Comment: Any object that implements `__iter__` passes your check. What are you trying to accomplish with this? Doesn't seem like good practice at all at first sight, and it's unclear where you would place the boundary between "iterable" or "non iterable" objects. This question doesn't make much sense without additional context, it's opinion based / too broad at best.

Comment: @Marco Bonelli: I would coarsely say a string is still a compact object in memory. A list collects pointer to objects scattered around in memory.

Comment: What’s the difference between a list consisting of single characters, and a string? Nothing in terms of iteration. “Compact object in memory” is a pretty wishy washy criterion.

Comment: @Friedrich which is exactly why I am saying this is opinion based at best. If you want to define "iterable" as something different from how the language defines it, then go ahead, but it's really just an opinion.

Comment: @deceze: `int` is also a collection of bits, but `int` is not iterable.

Comment: Well, everything is a collection of bits eventually somewhere down the stack. The real question is what you’re trying to use this for, this might get us closer to a solution. In what circumstances do you need to distinguish between a collection object (I’m guessing that’s what you’re asking?) and something other languages might call a “primitive”?

Comment: "often it is desirable to regard `str` not as list-like". Such as... when? (And no, I don't count "I want to my function to differentiate between containers and non-containers" as an example. Such functions are almost always better written as taking containers, and the caller can write `foo([x])` if there's only a single value to pass.)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it's good to use `__iter__` to check the type, there is a better choice for this one, the `Iterable` type.

It's your own opinion to divide the groups, so I think the easiest way is to set blacklists...

```
try:
    from collections.abc import Iterable # py3
except ImportError:
    from collections import Iterable #py2


def check(arg):
    if not isinstance(arg, Iterable):
        return False
    elif isinstance(arg, (str, bytes)):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: @deceze: I'd recommend replacing `bytes` with `collections.abc.ByteString` if you're on a modern enough Python to have it; that'll cover `bytes`, `bytearray` and other `bytes`-like types all at once. Assuming you *want* `bytes`-like types to be treated as non-iterable; in practice, treating them as iterable is less of a problem, since unlike `str`, they're iterables of `int`, not iterables of `str` (which can lead to infinite recursion).

Answer (score -1):

Edited:
To not trigger confusion with my answer I am quoting the docs here.

> class collections.abc.Iterable
>
> ABC for classes that provide the **iter**() method.
>
> Checking isinstance(obj, Iterable) detects classes that are registered
>   as Iterable or that have an **iter**() method, *but it does not detect
>   classes that iterate with the **getitem**() method. The only reliable
>   way to determine whether an object is iterable is to call iter(obj)*.

This works in 2 and 3.
`str`is iterable of course.

```
n1 = 1
s1 = 'abc'

objs = [n1, s1]

for o in objs:
    try:
        iter(o)
    except TypeError:
        print(o, 'is not Iterable!')
    else:
        print(o, 'is Iterable!')
```

Output:

```
1 is not Iterable!
abc is Iterable!
```

The quote was taken from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html?highlight=iterable#collections.abc.Iterable)

Comment: And this is exactly what OP wants to avoid.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to come up with our own definitions of iterable. `str` *is* a Python iterable. Maybe you should then came up with an abstract definition for our own new type and maybe register str as such?

Comment: And the other answer while partially good also contradicts the official docs.

Comment: This is all because the question itself does not make any sense to begin with. It is opinion based, broad and unclear. *"I don't think it is a good idea to come up with our own definitions of iterable"* - agree. OP does not refer to the Python definition of "iterable". Just avoid answering.